Find streak of hot days based on values in another column
I have a dataframe as below and I want to find streak ofh hot days.
dates = pd.date_range(start ='1-1-2018', end ='1-10-2018', freq ='1D')
np.random.seed(42)
temp = np.random.randint(60, 80, size=10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': dates, 'temp':temp})
df["is_hot"] = np.where(df["temp"] > 70, 1, 0)

This creates a dataframe as below:




dates
temp
is_hot




0
2018-01-01 00:00:00
66
0


1
2018-01-02 00:00:00
79
1


2
2018-01-03 00:00:00
74
1


3
2018-01-04 00:00:00
70
0


4
2018-01-05 00:00:00
67
0


5
2018-01-06 00:00:00
66
0


6
2018-01-07 00:00:00
78
1


7
2018-01-08 00:00:00
70
0


8
2018-01-09 00:00:00
70
0


9
2018-01-10 00:00:00
63
0



I am able to find streaks but I want them to break when we get is_hot value as 0 in between.
I use this
df['streak'] = df.loc[df['is_hot'].eq(1)].groupby(df['is_hot'])['is_hot'].cumsum()





dates
temp
is_hot
streak




0
2018-01-01 00:00:00
66
0
nan


1
2018-01-02 00:00:00
79
1
1


2
2018-01-03 00:00:00
74
1
2


3
2018-01-04 00:00:00
70
0
nan


4
2018-01-05 00:00:00
67
0
nan


5
2018-01-06 00:00:00
66
0
nan


6
2018-01-07 00:00:00
78
1
3


7
2018-01-08 00:00:00
70
0
nan


8
2018-01-09 00:00:00
70
0
nan


9
2018-01-10 00:00:00
63
0
nan



In my example, I want the streak value for 2018-01-07 to be 1. I can fill the nas with 0, so that should not be a problem.

Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, post the text itself and use the formatting tools like code formatting (print(df)) or table formatting (print(df.to_markdown()).

df.groupby(df['is_hot'].ne(1).cumsum())['is_hot'].cumcount()

Does this help? Make Pandas groupby act similarly to itertools groupby

@mozway That's not a duplicate. There, groups are uniquely identified by c1, c2, but here they're identified by is_hot and sequence. But I bet there's a duplicate out there.

There might be a better duplicate, I'll have a look

It'd help to seed the RNG so that we get reproducible data, like numpy.random.seed(0). This is covered at How to make good reproducible pandas examples

@wjandrea Will take care of formatting.
The solution you suggested doesn't work but I think I will be able to tweak it to get to my exact needs. Can you please explain your solution
df.groupby(df['is_hot'].ne(1).cumsum())['is_hot'].cumcount()

@rAmAnA mozway said that, not me

@mozway - can you please explain how your solution works?

@wjandrea - apologies! missed tagging them.

Fair enough, I didn't find an exact duplicate. I'll add the solution with a description.

You can form groups with cumsum, then use groupby.cumcount:
df['streak'] = df.groupby(df['is_hot'].ne(1).cumsum()).cumcount()

Output:
                 dates  temp  is_hot  streak
0  2018-01-01 00:00:00    66       0       0
1  2018-01-02 00:00:00    79       1       1
2  2018-01-03 00:00:00    74       1       2
3  2018-01-04 00:00:00    70       0       0
4  2018-01-05 00:00:00    67       0       0
5  2018-01-06 00:00:00    66       0       0
6  2018-01-07 00:00:00    78       1       1
7  2018-01-08 00:00:00    70       0       0
8  2018-01-09 00:00:00    70       0       0
9  2018-01-10 00:00:00    63       0       0

Intermediates:
                 dates  temp  is_hot  ne(1)  ne(1).cumsum()  streak
0  2018-01-01 00:00:00    66       0   True               1       0
1  2018-01-02 00:00:00    79       1  False               1       1
2  2018-01-03 00:00:00    74       1  False               1       2
3  2018-01-04 00:00:00    70       0   True               2       0
4  2018-01-05 00:00:00    67       0   True               3       0
5  2018-01-06 00:00:00    66       0   True               4       0
6  2018-01-07 00:00:00    78       1  False               4       1
7  2018-01-08 00:00:00    70       0   True               5       0
8  2018-01-09 00:00:00    70       0   True               6       0
9  2018-01-10 00:00:00    63       0   True               7       0

Alternatively, a solution without groupby, using a mask, ffill, and sub:
m = df['is_hot'].eq(1)
s = m.cumsum()
df['streak'] = s.sub(s.mask(m).ffill(), fill_value=1-df['is_hot'].iloc[0]
                     ).astype(int)

Intermediates:
                 dates  temp  is_hot      m  s  s.mask(m).ffill()  streak
0  2018-01-01 00:00:00    66       0  False  0                  0       0
1  2018-01-02 00:00:00    79       1   True  1                  0       1
2  2018-01-03 00:00:00    74       1   True  2                  0       2
3  2018-01-04 00:00:00    70       0  False  2                  2       0
4  2018-01-05 00:00:00    67       0  False  2                  2       0
5  2018-01-06 00:00:00    66       0  False  2                  2       0
6  2018-01-07 00:00:00    78       1   True  3                  2       1
7  2018-01-08 00:00:00    70       0  False  3                  3       0
8  2018-01-09 00:00:00    70       0  False  3                  3       0
9  2018-01-10 00:00:00    63       0  False  3                  3       0

Output with np.random.seed(17):
       dates  temp  is_hot  streak
0 2018-01-01    75       1       1
1 2018-01-02    77       1       2
2 2018-01-03    75       1       3
3 2018-01-04    66       0       0
4 2018-01-05    76       1       1
5 2018-01-06    73       1       2
6 2018-01-07    64       0       0
7 2018-01-08    67       0       0
8 2018-01-09    72       1       1
9 2018-01-10    67       0       0


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range(start='1-1-2018', end='1-10-2018', freq='1D')
np.random.seed(42)
temp = np.random.randint(60, 80, size=10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': dates, 'temp': temp})

df['is_hot'] = np.where(df['temp'] > 70, 1, 0)


streaks = df.groupby((df['is_hot'] == 0).cumsum())['is_hot'].cumcount().where(df['is_hot'] == 1, 0) 

df['streak'] = streaks

print(df[['dates', 'temp', 'is_hot', 'streak']])
'''
      dates  temp  is_hot  streak
0 2018-01-01    66       0       0
1 2018-01-02    79       1       1
2 2018-01-03    74       1       2
3 2018-01-04    70       0       0
4 2018-01-05    67       0       0
5 2018-01-06    66       0       0
6 2018-01-07    78       1       1
7 2018-01-08    70       0       0
8 2018-01-09    70       0       0
9 2018-01-10    63       0       0
'''

